# How to close triangle path?

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have drawn this shape:

[image]

here is my code:

```
/* build path */
let bottomBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
//first thing draw bottom line
bottomBezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, TRIANGLE_EDGE))
bottomBezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(bottomShapeLayer.frame.size.width,TRIANGLE_EDGE))

//now draw triangle
bottomBezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(bottomShapeLayer.frame.size.width,TRIANGLE_EDGE))
bottomBezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(bottomShapeLayer.frame.size.width,0))
bottomBezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(bottomShapeLayer.frame.size.width,0))
bottomBezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(bottomShapeLayer.frame.size.width - TRIANGLE_EDGE ,TRIANGLE_EDGE))

bottomShapeLayer.path = bottomBezierPath.CGPath
bottomShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
bottomShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
```

But I need to fill the triangle with red color, `bottomShapeLayer.fillColor` should do it, right ?

Comment: try bottomShapelayer.background=uicolor().redcolor;

Comment: @KishoreKumar thank you for your comment, but it doesn't work, it drew rectangle instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You're creating 2 separate line segments for your triangle.

**Each time you use `moveToPoint()`, you're starting a new line segment.** Therefore, when the `CAShapeLayer` comes to fill the triangle, it is unable to fill it, as it's 'incomplete'.

The fix to this is *really* simple, you just have to create a continuous path for your triangle by removing one of the `moveToPoint()` calls:

```
let bottomBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
//first thing draw bottom line
bottomBezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, TRIANGLE_EDGE))
bottomBezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(bottomShapeLayer.frame.size.width,TRIANGLE_EDGE))

//now draw triangle
//bottomBezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(bottomShapeLayer.frame.size.width,TRIANGLE_EDGE)) // this line is redundant btw, as you're moving to the same point. I've left it in incase you want to start your triangle somewhere else.
bottomBezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(bottomShapeLayer.frame.size.width,0))
bottomBezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(bottomShapeLayer.frame.size.width - TRIANGLE_EDGE ,TRIANGLE_EDGE))
```

**It's also worth noting that your `moveToPoint()` call at the *beginning* of the triangle is also redundant, as it's moving to the same point.**

Now you have a complete triangle and it should get filled correctly.

[image]